# How do I remove linebreaks in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, linebreaks

Is there a simple way of removing linebreaks in Notepad++?

For example:

```
This text has been splitted
in lines, and it's longer than
3200 words, so it would be great
to find and replace line breaks
like these.
```

Comment: Hmm, in VI it would be just typing `4J`

Comment: If you are looking to compose something like a URL from putting the URI parameters on multiple lines, then this answer is a bit more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13990281/501113

Comment: Do you expect spaces added:
"This text has been splitted in lines, and it's longer than 3200 words..."
or no spaces added:
"This text has been splittedin lines, and it's longer than3200 words..."
Each result requires a different technique.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

1. Highlight the lines you want to join (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything)
2. Choose **Edit → Line Operations → Join Lines** from the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

It will put in spaces automatically if necessary to prevent words from getting stuck together

Comment: Thanks but i has to be done one by one, is there a way to do this for the entire document?

Comment: I get it now, I selected the entire document and works exactly like I needed!

Comment: CTRL J is the shortcut

Comment: Tip: You might need to hit CTRL + J more than once. Do not use >View >Word wrap, to better see the linebreaks.

Comment: how can I *disable* adding spaces?

Comment: I think you would have to use the Find/Replace method given in the other answers, you need to leave the Replace text completely empy

Comment: Is there a hack to also rejoin words that were hyphenated across lines?

Answer (score 59):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

In `Search Mode` pick `Extended`

Find - `\r\n`
Replace - leave it empty.

Comment: I believe it needs to be **\r\n** since this is for Windows.

Comment: It should be `\r\n` and the replace field should contain one space character.

Comment: @JamesP, what is the difference? And why so in Windows?

Comment: @user1993: The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline has detailed information about how linebreaks work on different operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

For me, using Win 7, I had to use

> \r

in the `Find` box and type in `<space>` in the `Replace` box so that there is a single space between the last word of the current line and the first word of the next line.

Comment: Did you mean `\n`

Comment: No, I mean \r. \n does nothing on my system.