# How to remove linebreaks in Notepad++? in long text

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, linebreaks

I would like to know if is a method to remove linebreaks in Notepad++ aside from

```
 select  and   cntrl + J
```

that is already explain here

[How to remove linebreaks in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/518229/how-to-remove-linebreaks-in-notepad)

the Problem is that im trying to do a DML throught Excel to Notepad++ and when i copy the cells (from excel to notepad ++) it look like like this

```
-- Input 

 Insert into  table (
     line 1,
     line 2,
     line 3 ..

 Insert into  table (
     line 1,
     line 2,
     line 3..


--Output 

   Insert into table ( line1, line2,..)
   Insert into table (line1,line2,...)
    ...
```

so select each insert and make cntr + J is of course a solution but I wonder if there is any better that dont make me doing Manual 1 to 1 (because the DML in Excel could have like 1000 rows)

Comment: huh, ctrl with capital j, will add a new line, not remove one and can you show some the output you want. And anyhow, surely you can look up how to remove new lines, it's just search for either \r or \r\n and replace with nothing. That has to have been asked before, and if all you're asking is how to remove all new lines then there's no need for any text example, as people know what new lines are.

Comment: and you can do e.g. searching for some text up to a new line. `into[^\r\n]*`

Comment: hi @barlop  !! thanks for answer , if you do that find and replace \n then u have a very Long row, but just one. is the same like cntrl A + cntrl + J .

Comment: the find section has the new line \r or \r\n  or \n,  the replace section should not have \r or \r\n or \n.   In Windows generally one uses \r\n  in linux \n. So you might want \r\n

Comment: @barlop  find and replace  doesnt work for me with "\r\n"  just "\n" do you know why ??  i dont know if ist important but is at the end of the Notepad++ "UNIX in UTF-8 . it does matter?

Comment: it's fine. _._._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is very specific and my not be accurate, but assuming it is ...

`<space>Insert`

or

`<many spaces><some value>`

You want to leave the single space lines alone, remove `\n` from the rest.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or Ctrl + H)
- Set "Find what" to "\n[space][space]*"
- Set "Replace with" "[nothing]"
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

Where [space] is an actual space. That takes any pattern with at line break, followed by least 2 spaces and flattens it out. Then fix the blank space on the first line.

For reference: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: hi @lan W  , thanks for your answer , your solutions is Valid , Worked , thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I removed linebreaks in Notepad++?

I can't give you a perfect solution as your example input is incomplete, but you can start with the following.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\r\n +`
- Set "Replace with" to nothing
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]
- Set "Find what" to `\r\n\r\n`
- Set "Replace with" to `\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
Insert into  table (
     line 1,
     line 2,
     line 3 ..

Insert into  table (
     line 1,
     line 2,
     line 3..
```

**After**:

```
Insert into  table ( line 1, line 2, line 3 ..
Insert into  table ( line 1, line 2, line 3..
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: Thanks @davidPostill for your answer it look like pretty good, but i dont know why i dont why  cntrl  + h and find  \r\n or \r doesnt give me any resul "0 ocurrence was replaced" do you know why ? 

I dont know if is important but is in "UNIX"  "UTF-8" under the Notepad ++

Comment: `\r\n` is <cr><lf> (newline) on Windows. See [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15433188)

Comment: hi @DavidPostill  thanks for the link and i Change may Notepad++(to Windows) just to try, 
"\r\n"  work in the same way that did in Unix "\n" so take all the text and Change it in a single line but the step  2) 
•Set "Find what" to \r\n\r\n


•Set "Replace with" to \r\n

 doesnt have any reault ... do you have a clue why ?

Comment: No. It works with your test data. Maybe you have extra spaces? Try `\r\n +\r\n` (In step 1 " +" matches spaces)

Comment: If you have Unix <eol>s then use `\n` instead of `\r\n`

Comment: yes i know @DavidPostill  i would like to thank you for your answer but it dosent work for me These "+" , i know take it time ... and i would like to thank you .. but the true is that  worked for me , like this 
1) cntrl + A (select all text)
2) cntrl + J (all in one line)
3) find and replace
     find what:      Insert
     Replace with:  \r\n Insert

Comment: I would like to validate your answer but i tryed and didn work for me , sorry :_(

Comment: Then the data in your file doesn't match the sample data in the question :/