# Move lines based on ending of previous line

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Looking to get some insight as I'm lost on this one. I'd like to move lines based on the ending of previous one. It's a large CSV file that has a comment column that exported in line breaks from the original software. Sometimes there's only one line jump sometimes theres a few and sometimes none. The only saving grace in this output is that the line will always end with a number finishing by 0;

Source:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;0;
a;b;c;d;e;f
f continued;0;
a;b;c;d;e;f;140;
a;b;c;d;e;f
f continued
and continued again;0;
```

What I'm looking to achieve

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;0;
a;b;c;d;e;f f continued;0;
a;b;c;d;e;f;140;
a;b;c;d;e;f f continued and continued again;0;
```

Comment: How big is "large"?  You can remove line breaks with Notepad++, and several other text editors.

Comment: 20 527 lines in total.

Comment: Yeah, use Notepad++ to remove the newlines https://superuser.com/questions/518229/how-do-i-remove-linebreaks-in-notepad

Comment: Would I be able to only remove lines not ending in 0;?

Comment: Yes, you can use regex to match what you want to remove

Comment: what kind of csv format?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample file, just remove the carriage return in all lines that do not end with a semicolon.

In notepad++ you can use regex, search `([^;])$(\r|\n)+` and replace it with `\1` , to obtain your goal.

Here you can see the regex in action https://regex101.com/r/4Mw4iW/1

[image]